# If $|\frac{f(x)}{x} - \frac{\lfloor{nx}\rfloor}{nx}|\leq \frac{1}{n|x|}$ then $f(x)$ = $x$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0) = 0$. If we have:
$$
  |\frac{f(x)}{x} - \frac{\lfloor{nx}\rfloor}{nx}|\leq \frac{1}{n|x|} 
$$
for all $x \in \Bbb{R} \setminus 0$ and for all $n \in \Bbb{Z_{+}}$, can we say $f(x) = x$?
Here is what I thought:
We can show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lfloor{nx}\rfloor}{nx} = 1$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n|x|} = 0$ for fixed $x$. Hence $\frac{f(x)}{x}=1$ for $x \neq 0$. Since $f(0) = 0$, $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Is this logic correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you!